# How to include previously excluded URLS in a nutch crawl

Tags: hadoop, nutch

Using Nutch 2.1

During initial crawling, I had excluded some urls to limit the number of pages to be crawled. Now when I remove those reject rules from regex-urlfilter.txt and run these command, I dont get those filtered urls:

```
bin/nutch updatedb
bin/nutch generate
bin/nutch fetch -all
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This post](http://www.mail-archive.com/user@nutch.apache.org/msg09626.html) over nutch user group might help you do that.